# Yet Another: How to Ethernet over USB to Pi Zero (Pop!_OS 20.04LTS edition!)

Tags: usb, ethernet, pi-zero

I have been trying to get this new Raspberry Pi Zero W going, for the Pwnagotchi project. I `dd`'d the img over, made the appropriate `config.toml`, `config.txt`, and `cmdline.txt` changes as per every blog and previous reddit post I could get my hands on...

And nothing works.

I am running three things while plugging the Pi into my laptop:

- `watch -n1 ifconfig`
- `dmesg -w`
- `watch -n1 ls /dev`

And I let the Pi take a full two minutes to make sure it's getting all the way through its boot process.

Nothing. No logs per `dmesg`, and no changes or blips under the other two commands. I have tried multiple `cmdline.txt` variations:

- `modules-load=dwc2,g_ether`
- `modules-load=dwc2,g_serial`
- `modules-load=dwc2,g_cdc`

I have also tried multiple `config.txt` variations:

- `dtoverlay=dwc2`
- `dtoverlay=dwc2,dr_mode=peripheral`
- `dtoverlay=dwc2
  dr_mode=peripheral`

I have checked the `interfaces.d` config for `usb0-cfg`; all's clear there:

```
allow-hotplug usb0
iface usb0 inet static
address 10.0.0.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 10.0.0.0
broadcast 10.0.0.255
gateway 10.0.0.1
```

Sooo.... I have no idea what I could tweak or push next. My main driver is a Linux(Pop!_OS)20.04LTS laptop, but I have also tried connecting it to a MacBook2018(Catalina10.15.2) with all the same nothingness.

Promise that I have been googling and searching reddit, and I am finding a lot, but nothing yet has helped me get it working, OR even find some artifacts of what error there even is.

P.S. Yes the USB to microUSB cable supports data transfer and is not just for charging.

Comment: `I dd'd the img over` - what does this mean? I know what `dd` is, you just haven't specified what "img" is and where "over" is

Comment: I’ve deleted my notes as I have an objection to the uses the Pwnagotchi AI is designed for.  I can see no legal reason for this project and the ‘reinforcement learning’ is a feeble excuse in my mind.